# Where is the time being spent?

Tags: c++

I have a xml file, that contains record element. I am converting data inside record element to PCAP format.  The code is shown below. Within the do loop, i am only spending 6 miliseconds, but when i take time exactly at the boundaries of loop, it shows i am spending 43 miliseconds.. where is this difference comming from?
Also, i am new'ing up the memory inside the loop. Is that acceptable practice or should i zero up the memory and reuse it? Will reuse give any performance gains?
The time within loop is as shown below

2012-05-14 07:26:48 ThreadID(19404) TRACE:start Time:1030466589,End Time:1030466589

2012-05-14 07:26:48 ThreadID(19404) TRACE:start Time:1030466590,End Time:1030466590

2012-05-14 07:26:48 ThreadID(19404) TRACE:start Time:1030466591,End Time:1030466591

2012-05-14 07:26:48 ThreadID(19404) TRACE:start Time:1030466591,End Time:1030466591

2012-05-14 07:26:48 ThreadID(19404) TRACE:start Time:1030466592,End Time:1030466592

2012-05-14 07:26:48 ThreadID(19404) TRACE:start Time:1030466593,End Time:1030466593

2012-05-14 07:26:48 ThreadID(19404) TRACE:start Time:1030466593,End Time:1030466593

2012-05-14 07:26:48 ThreadID(19404) TRACE:start Time:1030466594,End Time:1030466594

2012-05-14 07:26:48 ThreadID(19404) TRACE:start Time:1030466595,End Time:1030466595

But time on boundary of do loop is
2012-05-14 07:26:48 ThreadID(19404) TRACE:start Time:1030466584,End Time:1030466627

```
        static struct tms st_cpu;
        static struct tms et_cpu;
        clock_t end_time;
        clock_t start_time;
        char szData[100] = {0};
        clock_t st_total_time;
        clock_t et_total_time;
        static struct tms st_total_cpu;
        static struct tms et_total_cpu;
        st_total_time = times(&st_total_cpu);
        do {
        char *pBuffer = new char[m_nBufferLen];
        memset(pBuffer,0,m_nBufferLen);
            if(fgets(pBuffer,m_nBufferLen,fpcap) != NULL)
            {
                    char *pRecord = NULL;
                    if((pRecord = strstr(pBuffer,"<rec ")) != NULL)
                    {
                            start_time = times(&st_cpu);
                            CXMLParser objXMLParser(pBuffer);
                            objXMLParser.ProcessRecord();
                            objPCAPGenerator.GeneratePCAPRecord(&objXMLParser);
                            end_time = times(&et_cpu);

                            sprintf(szData,"start Time:%ld,End Time:%ld",start_time,end_time);
                            CLog::PrintLog(DBG_TRACE,"%s",szData);


                            sprintf(szData,"Real Time: %ld,UserTime:%ld,SystemTime:%ld",
                                            end_time-start_time,
                                            (et_cpu.tms_utime + et_cpu.tms_cutime) - (st_cpu.tms_utime + st_cpu.tms_cutime),
                                            (et_cpu.tms_stime + et_cpu.tms_cstime) -(st_cpu.tms_stime + st_cpu.tms_cstime)
                                            );
                            CLog::PrintLog(DBG_TRACE,"%s",szData);
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                    bEnd = true;
            }
    }while(bEnd != true);

    et_total_time = times(&et_total_cpu);

    sprintf(szData,"start Time:%ld,End Time:%ld",st_total_time,et_total_time);
    CLog::PrintLog(DBG_TRACE,"%s",szData);


    sprintf(szData,"Total Real Time: %ld,Total UserTime:%ld,Total SystemTime:%ld",
                    et_total_time-st_total_time,
                    (et_total_cpu.tms_utime + et_total_cpu.tms_cutime) - (st_total_cpu.tms_utime + st_total_cpu.tms_cutime),
                    (et_total_cpu.tms_stime + et_total_cpu.tms_cstime) -(st_total_cpu.tms_stime + st_total_cpu.tms_cstime)
                    );
    CLog::PrintLog(DBG_TRACE,"%s",szData);
```

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't profile the code ?

Comment: not yet familiar with gdb or valgrind

Comment: Does your input file have a lot of lines that don't contain "<rec "? Your inner loop measurement doesn't reflect time spent reading and skipping unwanted lines.

Comment: no my entire file has "<record>data</record>" on every line

Comment: Your `strstr` is searching for "<rec ". Note the trailing space, that shouldn't match "<record".

Comment: @Jimm: now might be a good time to invest some effort in learning to use a profiler - it's much more productive in the long run than trying to guess where the bottlenecks in your code are (ditto for learning to use a debugger versus guessing where the bugs are)

Comment: @jimm: its time to learn valgrind.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, allocating memory is a relatively costly operation, so you should definitely re-use your allocated chunk of memory if this is performance critical code.

Also, remember to delete that memory you're allocating. I don't see it being done right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can and should of course profile your code, but just from a glimpse of it, I see two basic problems:

1. you are reallocating the buffer for each iteration. is that necessary or can you work with the same buffer? BTW you don't need to memset it to 0 before reading, just put a trailing zero after the string read.
2. is it necessary to read from the file in each iteration? if the file is huge and can't fit in memory, it's necessary of course. if the file has a known relatively small size, just read it to one big buffer, then parse it, it will be much much faster.

Comment: Instead of buffering myself, i am using kernel level and C API level buffering. Hence, i open the file with fadvise of FADV_SEQUENTIAL .Also, i am setting setvbuf, which allows further caching. Hence, the reads you see with fgets, are virtually free and happening from API Buffers.

Comment: Also, can you please give an example of what you meant by trailing zeros after string read?

Comment: @Jimm: You don't need to use `memset` or manually add the null terminator, `fgets` already adds a null terminator. BTW: your code has a terrible memory leak.

Comment: @Jimm: You immediately `fgets` over the contents of the buffer. Time spent zero-filling it is wasted.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. So the next fgets overwrites the previous fgets and if the next fgets fetches a smaller line, then it place null terminator, such that previous fgets contents are discarded

Comment: @jimm re the memory leak - you don't delete the allocated buffer at the end of iteration. unless the xml parser takes care of that, please do that. but again, if the parser copies it, just work on the same buffer the whole time.

Comment: @Jimm: Yes, the previous contents would be overwritten and the null terminator indicates the end of the string. The bigger issue is that you repeatedly `new[]` more memory and don't appear to `delete[]` it. That must be corrected.